# android - stop animation

Tags: java, android, graphics

In my program an image is animated vertically. I'd like the animation to stop at the right margin. I think the condtion in the second if-sequence should say that, but how do i stop the invalidate() method to animate at that point?

```
private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate(); 
        }
    };

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  

        BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);  
        if (x<0) {
            x = this.getWidth()/2;
            y = this.getHeight()/3;
        } 

            else {
                x += xVelocity;

                    if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {





                    }
            }

        c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  

        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);


    } 
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: In what way is it unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);` only if you want to continue the animation.

One way to achieve this is with a boolean (let's call it `continueAnimation`) which you set depending on the position of the animated item. Then you can write

```
c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  
if ( continueAnimation )
   {
       h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
   }
```